# HTACCESS redirect from subfolder to php file in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

hello I have a website that includes an /admin folder
in this folder I have a login.php file

How can I make it redirect the website.com/admin to website.com/admin/login.php using .htaccess inside the /admin folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/admin/.htaccess` you can have this line:

```
DirectoryIndex login.php
```

This will load `login.php` if `/admin/` is requested.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is even simpler and can be done like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin$
RewriteRule .* http://yourhostname.tld/admin/login.php [L]
```

Just adjust the domain name to your needs.

Comment: RewriteRule .* /admin/login.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* login.php [L]
```

This will redirect all request to login.php if
1) requested resource is not an existing file
2) requested resource is not an existing directory
3) requested resource is not an existing link
4) This will be the last redirect rule used

Comment: I am afraid this is not what I asked for ! I want to specifically let the user when he launches website.com/admin to be directly directed to website.com/admin/login.php nothing more

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `RewriteRule` with:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/login.php [NC,L]
```

Works with `admin` or `admin/` or `AdMin`...